# Bootstrap - set min and max width of div - not number of columns

Tags: html, css

I need to make number of columns set according to width of screen not to chose if there is a 3, 4, 5 or 6

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), but can you please expand on your question -- it's a little difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish as it's written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your solution, you need the media query's for CSS

https://jsfiddle.net/Alan_van_Buuren/4w9wy73y/

```css
.column {
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .column {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  .column {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 519px) and (min-width: 100px) {
  .column {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column">One</div>
<div class="column">Two</div>
<div class="column">Three</div>
<div class="column">Four</div>
<div class="column">Five</div>
<div class="column">Six</div>
<div class="column">Seven</div>
<div class="column">Eight</div>
<div class="column">Nine</div>
<div class="column">Ten</div>
<div class="column">Eleven</div>
<div class="column">Tweelve</div>
```

Comment: YEAH - thats all about it - just some more tweaks... TYWM

Comment: Cool! i want see the final result.